# Configure Docker with Gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a simple project setup in Gitlab CI/CD using Docker to serve the site on a Container following this [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example). But I get "Container already in use..." error whenever there is a new job running on a push event. How do I "push" the new code to my already running website without taking it down or killing the container?

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml    

stages:
 - build

job 1:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - windows-test
    
  script:
    - docker build -t vuejs-cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app .
    - docker run -p 8080:80 --rm --name dockerize-vuejs-app-1 vuejs-cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container name is the same every time. Stop and remove the old container first.

Run `docker stop dockerize-vuejs-app-1` and `docker rm dockerize-vuejs-app-1` after `docker build`.

Beside that I would suggest to run your container detached (`-d`) with `--restart always` ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy)).

```
docker build -t vuejs-cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app .
docker stop dockerize-vuejs-app-1
docker rm dockerize-vuejs-app-1
docker run -p 8080:80 -d --restart always --name dockerize-vuejs-app-1 vuejs-cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel. It works perfectly. Also, one last question. After making change to the code, I have to physically refresh the website for the changes to appear. Is there a way in Docker to do a kinda "hot reload"?

Comment: No, that's depending on your app, but the web server only serves the files. You have to implement such an behavior yourself.